# Detect current language direction with SilverStripe translatable module

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe to build a website that should support both English (LTR) and Arabic (RTL) languages. In the templates I need to set the direction of the language.

```
<html lang="$ContentLocale" dir="$//SomethingHere//">
```

How can I detect the current language direction and provide that to the template?

Comment: Isn’t this already in SilverStrips default simple-theme?
`<% if $i18nScriptDirection %>dir="$i18nScriptDirection"<% end_if %>`
https://github.com/silverstripe-themes/silverstripe-simple/blob/master/templates/Page.ss#L31

Comment: thanks that did the trick ☺

Comment: plz mark 3dgoo's answer as correct, since it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.4 the [`i18n` has a `get_script_direction`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-i18n.html#_get_script_direction) function that returns "rtl" or "ltr". This can be called through the [template global variable](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-i18n.html#_get_template_global_variables) `$i18nScriptDirection`.

```
<html lang="$ContentLocale" dir="$i18nScriptDirection">
```

Comment: you got a vote for "steeling" whats in my comment above ;)